# Thunderbolt 3 vs 10 Gbit ethernet

Tags: ethernet

I am not sure if I chose the right stack to ask this but here it goes...

I try to find the differences/competitive advantages/disadvantages of thunderbolt compared to ethernet from a technological perspective

And thats without including speed as in "transfer rate"

What I would like to know is if thunderbolt (being essentially a PCIe interface) is more "native" compared to ethernet

Does this mean thunderbolt consumes less/more resources when transferring data on the same speed as ethernet?

And stuff like that...

Unfortunately searching on the web I only found comparisons with USB or Firewire etc and all of them focused on transfer speed none mentioned a direct comparison with ethernet which I suppose is also the main antagonist.

Comment: You're comparing apples to oranges - they serve completely different purposes. What's better: USB or Ethernet? Depends if you want to copy files to a flash drive or to a network drive.

Comment: you obviously (from what I gather from your response) less informed than me... USB cant be compared with ethernet cause its in a much higher layer.. usb needs to talk to the OS in order to perform a task... thunderbolt on the other hand is much more lower and talks directly to the cpu....

Comment: That's not my point. I'm saying that your comparison doesn't make sense because Thunderbolt and Ethernet have no (or few) common use cases. It's like asking for differences/advantages/disadvantages of a bike vs. wheelbarrow.